# Convert date string to UTC datetime

Tags: python

I returned dates between two given dates:

```
for date in rrule(DAILY, dtstart = date1, until = date2):
        print date_item.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

How to convert the `date_item` e.g. `2016-01-01` to ISO 8601 format like:`2016-01-01T18:10:18.000Z` in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a sample datetime object like shown below:

```
from datetime import datetime 
now = datetime.now()
print now
2016-09-21 16:59:18.175038
```

Here is the output, formatted to your requirement:

```
print datetime.strftime(now, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z")
'2016-09-21T16:59:18.000Z'
```

Here is a good site to refer the various options, I personally find it easier to use than Python's official docs:
http://strftime.org

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strftime` to convert `date_item` in any format as per your requirement.see the below example

```
current_time = strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ",gmtime())
print(current_time)
```

Output:

```
'2016-09-21T11:30:04Z'
```

so you can use like this:

```
from time import gmtime,strftime
import datetime
date_item = datetime.datetime.now()
print date_item.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
```